# How VBA sends "ENTER" to execute Web

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

How VBA sends "ENTER" to execute Web? When "5904" is filled in input in Web, then it needs manual press "ENTER" in keyborad. So how VBA in auto press it for web.

```
Public Sub Web()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

With ie
.Visible = True
.Navigate2 "https://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/statistics/monthly/st44.php?l=zh-tw"

While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
 Set ticker = ie.document.getElementById("input_stock_code")
 ticker.Value = "5904"

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try [Application.SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys)

Comment: Didn’t work.” Argument not optional” error

Comment: Post your attempt that returned that error.

Comment: How VBA acts “Enter” like visit web after filling value? Is there an other way?

Comment: 'Application.SendKeys("~")`

Comment: I found it needs a left “click” first in input and “Enter”. How to click it in input?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page does an xhr POST request so you can just mimic that adding the expected `Content-Type` header. I use clipboard to write out `table` matched by classname but you could loop the `trs` and `tds` of the `table` node.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutMonthlyStockTrading()
    'VBE>Tools>References>Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Dim http As Object, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "POST", "https://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/statistics/monthly/st44.php?l=zh-tw", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send "yy=2019&input_stock_code=5904"
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim clipboard As Object

    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    clipboard.SetText html.querySelector(".page-table-board").outerHTML

    clipboard.PutInClipboard
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```